# How to count numbers less than 10 in an array using ForEach in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to count numbers that are less than 10 in an array in PowerShell. I need to use ForEach loop.

```
cls 
$a = 0..9
$i = 0

foreach ($element in $a) {
    if ($element -gt 2)
    {
        $i = $i + 1
        Write-Host $i
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get the total of all the numbers less than 10 (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 = 45)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `-gt` ("greater-than") to `-lt` ("less-than") and change `2` to `10`:

```bsh
foreach ($element in $a) {
  if ($element -lt 10)
  {
    $i = $i + 1
  }
}
Write-Host "Counted $i numbers under 10"
```

Answer (score 0):

here's another way to get the count. it filters out the items that are NOT less than the limit, sends them to another $Var, and then uses the  `.Count` property of that new $Var. finally, it shows the list of less-than-the-limit numbers.

the code & comments seem clear, but if you have questions, please ask ... [*grin*]

```
# only the last 3 items are NOT less than 10
$NumberList = @(1,3,5,7,9,1,1,4,0,-1,-666,111,666,10)
$Limit = 10

$TotalNumbers = $NumberList.Count
# a ".Where()" method call would be more obvious
#    so would piping to `Where-Object`
#    however, the requirement is to use a "foreach" loop [*grin*] 
$LessThanLimit = foreach ($NL_Item in $NumberList)
    {
    if ($NL_Item -lt $Limit)
        {
        $NL_Item
        }
    }

'Total Numbers             = {0}' -f $NumberList.Count
'Numbers less than [ {0,3} ] = {1}' -f $Limit, $LessThanLimit.Count
"$LessThanLimit"
```

output ...

```
Total Numbers             = 14
Numbers less than [  10 ] = 11
1 3 5 7 9 1 1 4 0 -1 -666
```

Answer (score -1):

If you didn't have to use the foreach loop you could have done it in a single line (might be useful to someone that ends up here):

```
$Below_10=($ThisFileResult | Where-Object {$_ -lt 10}).Count
```

Comment: the OP required the use of a `foreach` loop. yes, your solution is FAR better - it matches the intent of the problem ... but it does not meet the artificial requirement to use a `foreach` loop.