# Iteration over a list with a for loop (Racket)

Tags: racket

I need help with writing a function that uses a for loop to iterate over a list of numbers and returns all numbers that are less than 10. I have no idea where to start if anyone could help with even a starting point I'd appreciate it.

Thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count numbers less than 10 in an array using foreach in powershelll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61407636/how-to-count-numbers-less-than-10-in-an-array-using-foreach-in-powershelll)

Comment: Start _somewhere_. For example, start by writing a procedure that takes a list argument and uses a `for` loop to build and return a list containing _all_ elements of the input list.

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" way to do such a thing is with the [`filter` procedure](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29). It takes a *predicate* (a procedure that indicates whether a condition is true) and a list, and produces a new list containing those elements in the input list that satisfy the predicate. For example, we can produce a list that contains only the even numbers from an input list of numbers like so:

```
(filter even? '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6))
;; => (0 2 4 6)
```

In your case, there's no "built in" predicate for testing whether a number is less than 10, but we can easily define one:

```
(define (<10 n)
  (< n 10))
```

and then filter any list using it:

```
(filter <10 '(1 4 15 23 25 4 8))
;; => (1 4 4 8)
```

In this case though, I think most would prefer to use a `lambda` instead:

```
(filter (lambda (n) (< n 10))
        '(1 4 15 23 25 4 8))
;; => (1 4 4 8)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. This is very helpful however I have been forced to use a for loop to the task required.

Thanks :)